# Which heroes can soak xp in a lane without being there?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Abathur can gain xp in a lane without being there with his symbiote, or if he has a live locust in the lane.  What other heroes have a mechanic like this?  Do Azmodan's spawns earn xp in a lane without Azmodan himself being there?  What about Gazlowe's turrets, Malfurions Treeant, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While any hero that summons other entities to do damage *can* get experience from a lane without being in the lane, Abathur is the only reliable one. Summoned creatures (Malfurion's treeant, Zagara's zerg summons, etc) or weapons (such as Gazlowe's turrets or Sgt. Hammer's spider mines) only give you experience if they get the last hit on a wave minion. If they do not get the last hit then you do not get experience, even if they are near the wave or have done damage to it.

Abathur is special in that when he places his symbiote on an ally, whether that is a wave minion, a camp minion, or his own locusts, the symbiote counts as him being there and will soak experience. His locusts act like any other hero's summon and do not give experience for just being nearby, only if they get the last hit.

Comment: So that would make Abathur and The Lost Vikings unique in their abilities to soak multiple lanes?  (Since Aba can put the symbiote in one lane while hiding in the brush of another lane)

Comment: Correct. Their strengths (and a huge part of their difficulty) come from being able to not necessarily push lanes by themselves, but to soak and let another one of their teammates leave their lane to go roam. At the moment, they are the only two heroes (Two? Four? I'll count TLV as 1) that can do this to more than one lane at a time.

Comment: Is Murky's pufferfish counted as a summon? Would it give experience even if Murky is dead already?

Comment: Murky's pufferfish itself would not give experience for just being near a minion because the pufferfish is not a hero. If Murky is alive, then he is likely close enough to soak experience for being in the lane himself. If he is dead, then as far as I am aware (and Leoric testing in [this comment](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/18300734751#19) suggests) that the moment you are dead you are considered out of combat and no longer get experience if something near where you were died. If the pufferfish kills any minions, then Murky would get normal experience for the kill.